# Submit one select field in ajax (not entire form) to get it's value and filter another select in php on same page

Tags: php, ajax, input

it's my first programming experience in Ajax (or Jquery) so i appreciate any kind of help.
What i am trying to do is that i have 2 select inputs in my html form i want when the first select is changed (onchange) to have its value to use it to filter the second select in php to dynamically generate its options, that must happen without submitting the entire form only the first select.
I tried the following code but whenever the first select changes it submit the entire form.
the ajax function:

```
function showKadaa(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{   
document.getElementById("kop").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","annonce.php?mid="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

the html code portion with php:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['mid']))
$q=$_GET['mid'];
else $q=$_SESSION['mid'];?>

//code goes here

<tr><td>Kadaa:</td><td><div id="kop"><select name="kadaa" id="kad" ><option value="default">[Choisir     Kadaa]</option>

<?php
            if(login_db()){                     
                $req="SELECT `nom_kadaa`,`id` FROM `kadaa` WHERE `id_mohafaza`=".$q.""; 
                echo $req;
                $kadaa="";
                if($res=mysql_query($req)){
                    while($l=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
                        echo "<option value=".$l[1].">".$l[0]."</option>";
                    }                       
                }
            }               
        ?>
</select></div></td></tr>
```

P.S: WHERE EVER I PUT THE div of id="kop"
the entire page is submited in it. Another thing i using the two select on same page with

```
form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>
```

Comment: So, erm, where's the jQuery? Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Indent the JS, would make it much easier to read. I've got know idea how you're activating the AJAX request.

Comment: hi @Flukey i said i am totaly new to ajax and jquery and it's my first try in it so i don't what is right and what is wrong! the code of the function showKadaa(str) i found it on the Internet for a similar application of mine! so if you could give any advice i will appreciated thanks

Comment: So you copied and pasted code you didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

for getting on field value:
jquery would love to use

```
$("#IdOfElement").val();
```

by the way, jquery has a lot more handy methods for ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```